# Minecraft is sometimes misremembering my username

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, steam, technical-issues

Lately, when I open the Minecraft launcher my username (“kpreid”) is sometimes replaced with “O” (just the one letter). The password is remembered correctly — if I retype the username I can log in. If I retype the username, **log in**, quit, and relaunch, then it remembers correctly for a while. I have not found how to reproduce the problem.

Has anyone seen this problem and figured out how to avoid or fix it?

Mac OS X 10.7.2
“New” (shows mcupdate site) Minecraft launcher, patched for 64-bit Java
Launched through Steam

---

Troubleshooting log:

2012-01-24: I launched MC through Steam and noticed the “O”. I immediately quit and relaunched it directly and saw “kpreid”, trying both several times to confirm the correlation. I then tried changing the Steam shortcut launch options to add a command-line argument, and that argument showed up as the login name (*persistently*), which suggests that perhaps Steam is generating a bogus “O” argument some of the time, or the way in which Steam launches MC results in it accessing files differently. The `lastlogin` file had identical contents before and after I logged in correctly.

2010-01-25: I saw a few occurrences of garbage including Steam-ish pathnames appearing in the login field.

Comment: I don't know about the cause, but maybe write-protecting `.minecraft/lastlogin` could solve this (`chmod -w` on MaxOS I guess)

Comment: Interesting thought; protecting, reverting, or comparing that file might help with troubleshooting too. I'll see if I can get around to that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on my observations (see log in question), I am reasonably confident that this is a Steam bug where it adds garbage to the arguments of the shortcut-launched program.

On Jan 26, I added my username explicitly to the arguments in the shortcut properties; this has prevented the problem from occurring so far as I've noticed, so it apparently only happens if no explicit arguments are provided.